# Import specific package from maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a maven project where I am using pom.xml to declare maven dependency.
I want to import a jar named "externalCard" but don't want to import all the packages inside that jar because few entity defined in the externalCard jar is also present in my project causing an error.
error:  A bean with that name has already been defined in class path

Is their any way such that i can import only the specific package or classes from the externalCard jar.

for eg externalCard has this structure

```
-externalCard
--com.external.card
----package1
------files
----package2
------files
```

I want to import files belong to only package1, as package2 files are already there in my projects

Comment: A jar is an atomic dependency, i.e. you cannot just import select packages. Your application or the framework you're using might be able to handle those conflicts or filter packages (e.g. you could have Spring scan specific packages only) but Maven isn't involved here - at least not directly.

Comment: Btw, it might help if you'd provide some more info, e.g. why do you already have those beans on your classpath, what frameworks your're using etc. You _could_ handle class conflicts with a classloader hierarchy etc. but that's a very complex task to it's often better to try and tackle the conflict right at the source.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, the class conflicts are entity and repository beans and the framework is spring boot, the problem is that i am working on a legacy code where these above mentioned entity and repository are heavily used and its impossible to used external jars classes becaused legacy code is prod code and working fine and it require lot of file changes

Comment: But i need to use few newly created entity and repository classes which are present in the external jars which i am importing through pom in main(legacy) project

Comment: Well, you could try to package those new entities and repositories into a separate jar. If they have dependencies on the other entities though you might still run into problems if there's an incompatibility between old and new versions of the entities and repos you don't want to have duplicates of. It's still a very theoretical discussion so without seeing code or having more details it's hard to make a suggestion.